# How do I give an array an attribute during serialization in C#?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-attribute

I'm trying to generate C# that creates a fragment of XML like this.

```
<device_list type="list">
    <item type="MAC">11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88</item>
    <item type="MAC">11:22:33:44:55:66:77:89</item>
    <item type="MAC">11:22:33:44:55:66:77:8A</item>
</device_list>
```

I was thinking of using something like this:

```
[XmlArray( "device_list" ), XmlArrayItem("item")]
public ListItem[] device_list { get; set; }
```

as the property, with this class declaration:

```
public class ListItem {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Which gives me the inner serialization, but I don't know how to apply the `type="list"` attribute to the `device_list` above.

I'm thinking (but not sure of how to write the syntax) that I need to do a:

```
public class DeviceList {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlArray]
    public ListItem[] .... This is where I get lost
}
```

Updated based on Dave's responses

```
public class DeviceList : List<ListItem> {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class ListItem {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and the usage is currently:

```
[XmlArray( "device_list" ), XmlArrayItem("item")]
public DeviceList device_list { get; set; }
```

And the type, while being declared in the code like thus:

```
device_list = new DeviceList{type = "list"}
device_list.Add( new ListItem { type = "MAC", Value = "1234566" } );
device_list.Add( new ListItem { type = "MAC", Value = "1234566" } );
```

Isn't showing the type on serialization. This is the result of the serialization:

```
<device_list>
  <item type="MAC">1234566</item>
  <item type="MAC">1234566</item>
</device_list>
```

So apparently I'm still missing something...

Comment: @jcolebrand- You need to add an XmlElement attribute to the ListType property of the DeviceList class.  See my updated below.

Comment: @jcolebrand- Here's some good reference on XML serializaton: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using part of Dave's answer above, I found that it was best to use the property in the declaring class like this: (note the lack of attributes)

```
public DeviceList device_list { get; set; }
```

and then update the DeviceList class like this:

```
[XmlType("device_list")]
[Serializable]
public class DeviceList {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement( "item" )]
    public ListItem[] items { get; set; }
}
```

and keep the original ListItem class

```
public class ListItem {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and my serialization is as expected:

```
<device_list type="list">
  <item type="MAC">1234567</item>
  <item type="MAC">123456890</item>
</device_list>
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out that adding the [XmlElement] attribute is the key here. According to MSDN:
_If you apply the XmlElementAttribute to a field or property that returns an array, the items in the array are encoded as a sequence of XML elements.
In contrast if an XmlElementAttribute is not applied to such a field or property, the items in the array are encoded as a sequence of elements, nested under an element named after the field or property._

Comment: This works great. It seems that you can even apply multiple XmlElement references if you have more than one type of child with the same parent type.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a `ListItem[]`, derive a new class from `List<T>` called DeviceList:

```
public class DeviceList : List<ListItem>
{
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "type")]
   public string ListType {get;set;}

}
```

Then, in a containing class use that class to serialize the XML.  The type value can be included as an element of the parent node, depending on the way you configure the serialization.  I don't remember the exact syntax, but I think class properties are added as node elements by default.

Containing class:

```
public class SerializeMyStuff
{
   public SeriazlieMyStuff()
   {
       ListOfDevices = new DeviceList();
       ListOfDevices.ListType = "list";
   }

   [XmlArray( "device_list" ), XmlArrayItem("item")]
   public DeviceList ListOfDevices {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: so where I use `[XmlArray( "device_list" ), XmlArrayItem("item")] public ListItem[] device_list { get; set; }` you're suggesting I should do what instead? Sorry for being dense, I just feel like I'm missing something here ...

Comment: ListItem[] is a primitive array of ListItems.  If you create a new class that derives from List<T>, you can add a new "type" property to that class.  That will give you the ability to set the "type" element in the serialized XML.

Comment: Updated the Q, so you can see what I'm doing and where I'm not seeing the serialization. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, no, that didn't work either .. but I found a solution

Answer (score 3):

You could also achieve the desired behaviour by implementing `[IXmlSerializable][1]` in your container class:

With the below code I get the following markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DeviceList type="list">
  <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="MAC">11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88</Item>
  <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="MAC">11:22:33:44:55:66:77:89</Item>
  <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="MAC">11:22:33:44:55:66:77:8A</Item>
</DeviceList>
```

code:

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceList : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } 


    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("type", Type);


        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item));
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
        }
    }
}
```

I use the following code in my main method:

```
var dlist = new DeviceList
                {
                    Type = "list",
                    Items = new List<Item>
                                {
                                    new Item {Type = "MAC", Value = "11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88"},
                                    new Item {Type = "MAC", Value = "11:22:33:44:55:66:77:89"},
                                    new Item {Type = "MAC", Value = "11:22:33:44:55:66:77:8A"},
                                }
                };


using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"D:\jcoletest.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    new XmlSerializer(typeof (DeviceList)).Serialize(stream, dlist);
}
```

For more information look at this [tutorial here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/ImplementIXmlSerializable.aspx)