# Serialization get node information

Tags: c#, xml

```
<SHEET>
<books title ='title'>
<book label='1' page='1' intro='1'/>
<book label='2' page='2' intro='2'/>
<book label='3' page='3' intro='3'/>
</books>

<books title ='title'>
<book label='1' page='1' intro='1'/>
<book label='2' page='2' intro='2'/>
<book label='3' page='3' intro='3'/>
</books>


</SHEET>
```

So i have this code, i use it to get the attributes inside the book item.
I use this code:

```
[XmlRoot("SHEET")]
public class BookRoot
{
    private readonly List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
    [XmlArray("books"), XmlArrayItem("book")]
    public List<Book> Books { get { return books; } }
}
public class Book {
    [XmlAttribute("label")]
}
```

I also need to retireve the books properties, how do i do it?

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790807/how-do-i-give-an-array-an-attribute-during-serialization-in-c

Comment: Hmm, thanks, it'S the reverse, from c# to XML and i'm not good in understanding it...

Comment: Well, serialization and desererialization uses the same c# class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class to serialize is not as good as it could be. Consider the use of such:

```
[XmlRoot("SHEET")]
public class Sheet
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("books")]
    public sheetBooks[] books;

    public Sheet()
    {}
}

public class sheetBooks
{
    [XmlAttribute("title")]
    public string title;

    [XmlElementAttribute("book")]   
    public sheetBook book;

    public sheetBooks()
    {}
}

public class sheetBook
{
    [XmlAttribute("label")]
    public char label;

    [XmlAttribute("page")]
    public char page;

    [XmlAttribute("intro")]
    public char intro;

    public sheetBook()
    {}
}
```

label, page, intro - they are allways below 10? In this case `char` should work. Otherwise, check result for `string` or `int`